# Azure Data Factory ARM Template has empty parameter for linked service connection string

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have some problems, that I am hoping someone can help me with.
I created a bunch of resources - few linked services, few datasets and few pipe lines in the Datafactory "DevDataFactory".
One of the linked services connecting to a SQL Database is configured this way
[image]

Then in the json for that linked service the connection string is seen in this snippet:

```
"typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=@{linkedService().cloudDbDomain};Initial Catalog=@{linkedService().dbName};User ID=@{linkedService().dbUserName}",
        "password": {
            "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
            "store": {
                "referenceName": "KeyVaultLink",
                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "secretName": "DBPassword"
        },
        "alwaysEncryptedSettings": {
            "alwaysEncryptedAkvAuthType": "ManagedIdentity"
        }
    }
```

All parameters are in place, default values are set and when
pipeline is run it asks for values.

The problem is that when I then go and export the ARM Template so to use the datafactory in another environment, there is a parameter there for this Linked Service's connection String, and this parameter value is blank.  ALL AND ANY OTHER PARAMETER used in the ARM template has some default value - why does this one not have it ?

**Given the parameters used inside the connection string are present and do have their own default values**.

If I use the Azure Portal to import that ARM Template, I can go ahead and enter the connection string, like from the json code snippent above

```
Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;Data Source=@{linkedService().cloudDbDomain};Initial Catalog=@{linkedService().dbName};User ID=@{linkedService().dbUserName}
```

.. and everything will be imported and all my pipelines will automatically work out from the newly created datafactory.

The PROBLEM IS that I need to do this from Azure Dev Ops pipelines, which are automatically picked up from Git repo "adf-publish" branch, and this is where I don't know what to do.  When ADO pipeline automatically runs, I can't just substitute the "connection string" on the fly.

I am stuck, please help !!

Comment: In the DevOps pipeline you should supply your own parameters.json file that has the values you want filled in.  Or you can override the parameters in the ARM deploy step if you prefer.  Typically things like connection strings are left blank in the parameters file in the adf-publish branch.

Comment: Thank you.  I found how to override the parameters in the ARM deploy task in the DevOps.  But, can you point me to where to learn about supplying my own parameters.json ?  I am new to this, and would like some resource on how to learn and apply the concepts, rather than chasing "similar problems"

Comment: All you really need to do is create your parameters file and store in your adf-publish branch in source control and then reference in your ARM deployment step.  Here is a starting point for ADF CI/CD process https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery